Programmaticaly get coordinates of area symbol in OSM
OpenStreetMap sometimes encodes buildings as areas - as closed ways instead of nodes. But still at some point in the map a symbol or a housenumber is placed. I want to get the coordinates of this exact point in the map. Optimal would be via Overpass API but any way that can be automated would be fine.
I already found out that it's not the center what I'm looking for. Otherwise this would be the solution: get center coordinates of a buiding(way)
Example
When I use this Overpass Query
way(id:761345550);
out center;

I get this result

As you see the point on the map is left to where OSM puts the symbol of Alnatura Super Natur Markt. I want the coordinates of where the shopping cart symbol is.

If you want the exact coordinates you probably need to tweak the OSM tile renderer code to care about the coordinates. As far as i recall, carthographic label placement on the micro level does not care about coordinates, only about not overlapping anything that it should not and staying inside a specified pixel distance to the "original" coordinate.
The renderer code is available at https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto .

The reason why this doesn't work with Overpass API is that the center point corresponds to the center of the way's bounding box (which is usually from the centroid or what ST_PointOnSurface returns).

Phew... After digging into this a couple of times I'm half sure that project.mml is the file to look for... However I don't see how these SQL querys will lead to tiles being generated and symbols being generated into them at some coordinates. My guess is that I need to learn CartoCSS to understand this file.
Am I even on the right way?
